# Inequality programming involving sum compositions

Tags: programming, summation, series-expansion

$n=3$,
$m=3$,
$B$ - identity matrix $3 \times 3$

Trying to implement it in Mathematica, but can't figure out how to program the second term. The result is an error.

[image]

```
Clear["Derivative"]
ClearAll["Global`*"]

n = 3
m = 3
B = IdentityMatrix[3]

Sum[x[i] f[i], {i, 1, n}] + 
 Sum[x[i], {i, 1, n}] Sum[B[[i, j]] u[i], {j, 1, m}] - 
 1/T Log[\[Alpha]/\[Beta]] Sum[x[i]^2, {i, 1, n}]
```

Comment: You can not write `Sum[B[[i, j]] u[i], {j, 1, m}]`where `i`  is undefined.

Comment: @DanielHuber

`Sum[x[i] Sum[B[[i, j]] u[i], {j, 1, m}], {i, 1, n}]`

I tried this construction, but it seems to me that it is not correct.

Comment: @DanielHuber

And no, I could be wrong, but it seems the last edit is correct?

Comment: No, I think the `i` in `B[[i,j]] u[i]` should indeed be bound by the same summation that the sum over `x[i]` is. `Sum[x[i] Sum[B[[i, j]] u[i], {j, 1, m}], {i, 1, n}]` should be correct.

Comment: Also, what exactly is the error you're getting?

Comment: The formula in the text is a bit misleading. The terms that depend only on `ì ` should not be in the sum over `j` . For short, the sum can be written in MMA as `Sum[x[i] u[i] B[[i, j]] , {j, 1, m}, {i, 1, n}]`Of course you can this also write with 2 `Sum`, but this is a bit clumsy.

Comment: @DanielHuber

I have an idea. Take a completely arbitrary condition, for example `Reduce[a*y - 1 <= 0 && a > 0, {y}, Reals]`. If we express the condition for $u$, we get $u<=1/a$.Is it possible to express also $u$ from those conditions (2) and (3) that are given in the article?

Comment: @thorimur

I have an idea. Take a completely arbitrary condition, for example `Reduce[a*y - 1 <= 0 && a > 0, {y}, Reals]`. If we express the condition for $u$, we get $u<=1/a$.Is it possible to express also $u$ from those conditions (2) and (3) that are given in the article?

Comment: I am not sure if the following will help, have a look. Consider (2). Call the first sum `a ` the third `b` and `xi Sum[bij {j,n}]` ci. Further consider `ui` and `ci` as vectors. `u` and `c` . We then have: `c.u <= b-a`. If we divide by the norm of c: `nc` we get   `c/nc .u <= (b-a)/nc`.  This can be interpreted as: The component of u in the direction of c must be smaller equal than `(b-a)/nc`. And the component of c perpendicular to c is arbitrary.